# When there is no text on ion-search bar the list should hide?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i stuck , please help me

I am using ion-searchbar , i want that when there is no text on the searchbar the list must be hide but the list is still showing
Can anyone help me?

in .html file

```html
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" class="" style="background-color: #073262 !important" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" style="background:none!important;"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openNavDetailsPage(item)">
        {{ item }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

in .ts file

```js
  getItems(ev) { 
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();
    // set val to the value of the ev target
    var val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` and `ngIf` :

```html
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchInput" (ionInput)="getItems($event)" class="" style="background-color: #073262 !important" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" style="background:none!important;"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list *ngIf="searchInput !== ''">
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openNavDetailsPage(item)">
        {{ item }}
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in .ts:

```js
public searchInput='';
```

**OR** 
If your variable `items` is empty at initalization :

```html
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" class="" style="background-color: #073262 !important" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" style="background:none!important;"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list *ngIf="items && items.length">
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openNavDetailsPage(item)">
        {{ item }}
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in .ts:

```js
public items = [];
```

Comment: when i am doing public items = []; then this error is coming [ts] A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

Comment: Did you try the solution with `searchInput` variable and `ngModel`?

Comment: when there is no text on search bar still list is showing @Augustin R

Comment: You're welcome, you should mark the question as resolved as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)